# GSON custom class containing map

Tags: dictionary, gson

I have an object which contains a map where each value in the map is another object which consists of some primitives and a list as follows:

```
Class A { 
    String sa;
    Map<B, B> mapOfBs;
}

Class B {
    String sb;
    List<C> listOfCs;
}

Class C {
    String sc;
}
```

For the sake of discussion, I have a class instance holding some info (which can be depicted from the parsed json below, not that important...).
When I use GSON to serialize this class it is retrieved on the server side as follows:

```
{
"sa": "aaaa",
"mapOfBs": {
    "k.l.z.B@405bb400": {
        "sb": "bbb",
        "listOfCs": []
    },
    "k.l.z.B@405bd968": {
         "sb": "bbbb2",
        "listOfCs": []
    }
}
```

This essentially causing an error when I am trying to deserialize the string. The exception I get is "`Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING`" pointing to where the fully qualified name of class B was embedded in the string.

My feeling is that something is going wrong with the class B parsing as I do not understand why the fully qualified name is inserted there. Also for the list (of Cs) it is not showing so my feeling is even stronger...

Anyone can help here? (thanks in advance)

Answer (score 0):

In your POJO you have declared a `Map`: `Map<B,B> mapOfBs`

You have JSON that ... isn't that.

```
"mapOfBs": {
    "k.l.z.B@405bb400": {
        "sb": "bbb",
        "listOfCs": []
    },
 ...
```

`"k.l.z.B@405bb400"` is most certainly not a `B` and Gson is telling you that - e.g. "But was String"

What you have in your JSON is: `Map<String, B> mapOfBs`

**Edit to add from commets below:** The reason your `Map` is being serialized this way is that the default serialization method in Gson for keys in a `Map` is to call `toString()` on the key. Your POJO doesn't override `toString()` so you're getting the `Object.toString()` output.

JSON itself does not support what you are trying to do. If you look at the specification for JSON ( http://www.json.org/ ) you will find it is composed of name/value pairs where the name portion is a string; you can't have an object on the left hand side.

Comment: Thanks Brian, my Map is declared: HashMap<B, B> but gson.toJson results in this fully qualified name of the object. So the error is obvious to me as well but my problem is - why would the gson.toJson parse my map to this unexpected result? (btw, meanwhile I just used a list instead of the map (less performing for my use case but dealing with low numbers here - not that crucial) and there you go - works like a charm)

Comment: See my edit. You can't have anything but a string on the left side of a JSON pair.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This explains my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this still helps.

You can try

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().enableComplexMapKeySerialization().create();
String jsonString = gson.toJson(object));
```